# Extracting machine code from a programmed microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I have a Texas Instruments EK-TM4C1294XL (ARM Cortex M4) evaluation kit that I had programmed some time ago to perform different tasks. Since then, my source code for the program was misplaced and now I want to program a second evaluation board to perform the same tasks as the first. I do not want to re-write the source code as it was very lengthy.

Is it possible to extract the compiled machine code or binary file from the originally programmed board and use that to program a new second board?

Comment: Do you know if the "lock" or "fuse" bit preventing the program ROM from being read out was set?  If so, then no, you cannot extract it.  Otherwise you should be able to plug it into a suitable TI or 3rd party development tool and read out the programming.

Comment: I don't remember setting any lock or fuse bit, so I don't think so @jwh20

Comment: The LM FLASH PROGRAMMER utility which is provided by TI to work with this board has the functionality (the `--upload` option as per [this thread](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/arm-based-microcontrollers-group/arm-based-microcontrollers/f/arm-based-microcontrollers-forum/840875/ek-tm4c1294xl-lm-flash-programmer-gui-and-command-line-documentation-and-examples)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the executable (object) code from it but definitely not the source code if it is not protected. You can use a disassembler to generate pseudo assembler code from the object code. It will generate its own labels etc.  With that you can modify it and put back into a micro. When you first generate it assemble it to be sure you get the same code back. I have not done this for a long time but you might find something that may convert the object code to source but I doubt it. Good Luck.